# OnClick Only works "once"

Tags: javascript, html

How I call the function:

```
function createHTML(){
...
monthDiv.setAttribute('onclick', 'onOptionSelected(`' + monthDiv.id + '`)');
....
}
```

-numSelected is the times that a div can be selected.

```
function onOptionSelected(option) {
        if(numSelected <= 2){
            numSelected ++;
            console.log("NUMSELECTEED: " + numSelected);
            selectedMonths.push(option);
            if ($('#' + option + '').hasClass("unSelected")) {
                $('#' + option + '').removeClass("unSelected").addClass("selected");

            } else if ($('#' + option + '').hasClass("selected")) {
                $('#' + option + '').removeClass("selected").addClass("unSelected");

            }
        }
    }
```

After you select 3 divs, nothing happens, the "onclick" doesn't work.

Actually, after you click 3 times in any box, two times the same box, doesn't matter, after 3 clicks, doesnt work.

Comment: Are there any errors seen in your Browser Console?

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle or a snippet?

Comment: No errors, I'll create it.

Answer (score 0):

you're creating multiple divs (i assume in some sort of for loop).
Delete the "numSelected" global variable declaration you have, and try something like this:

```
var aNumSelected[];

function createHTML(){
    ...
    monthDiv.setAttribute('onclick', 'onOptionSelected(`' + monthDiv.id + '`)');
    aNumSelected.push({ id : monthDiv.id, numSelected : 0 });
    ....
}

function onOptionSelected(option) { 
    var numSelected;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < aNumSelected.length(); i++){
        if (aNumSelected[i].id == option){
            numSelected = aNumSelected[i].numSelected;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(numSelected <= 2){
        numSelected ++;
        console.log("NUMSELECTEED: " + numSelected);
        selectedMonths.push(option);
        if ($('#' + option + '').hasClass("unSelected")) {
            $('#' + option + '').removeClass("unSelected").addClass("selected");

        } else if ($('#' + option + '').hasClass("selected")) {
            $('#' + option + '').removeClass("selected").addClass("unSelected");    
        }

        aNumSelected[i] = { id: option, numSelected: numSelected };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

numselected seems to be a global variable and therefore is shared by all divs.

You have to store a dedicated value for each div.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `numSelected` is most likely never being reset and is in a higher scope than you think. You increment it in this but it's the same value for all buttons. So on that third click, no matter the button pressed, `if(numSelected <= 2){` fails.